"Connectivity" of a surface in Hirsch's book
Exercise 9.17 in Hirsch's "Differential Topology" says the following:

The connectivity $c(M)$ of a compact surface $M$ is the integer $c\geq 0$ (if it exists) having the following property. Let $V\subset M$ be the union $V_1\cup\cdots\cup V_r$ where each $V_r$ is a neat arc, or a circle in $M-\partial M$, and $V_i$ and $V_j$ intersect transversely for $i\neq j$. Suppose $M-V$ is connected. Then $r\leq c$ and if $r<c$ then $V$ is a proper subset of another set $V'$ of the same type. If $\partial M$ has $b$ components then $c(M)=2-\chi(M)-b.$

If $M$ is the annulus, then $\chi(M)=0$ and $b=2$ but the arc connecting the two boundary circles is a legitimate $V_1$. Am I misunderstanding the statement of this problem?
And is there some other reference where the connectivity is discussed more thoroughly?

It is called "the first Betti number" in modern literature.

I am aware of a connection. But for me the Betti number is something about homology or harmonic forms; where can I see it formulated in terms of disconnecting cuts? I am sure it's well known but I'm rather weak on algebraic topology. Also, why doesn't the annulus give a counterexample to Hirsch's problem?

Is that arc contained in $M-\partial M$?

@TedShifrin In the annulus example, the arc is what Hirsch refers to as a neat arc, meaning that its boundary coincides with where it intersects $\partial M$ and that it does so transversally.

Oh, I missed the important comma. Sorry. We should have $c=1$ for the annulus, so the final formula seems wrong in this case, indeed.

The concept of connectivity goes back to none other than Bernhard Riemann. The precursor appears in §6 of his 1851 dissertation Grundlagen für eine allgemeine Theorie der Funktionen einer veränderlichen complexen Größe and it then appears in §2 of his 1857 paper Theorie der Abel’schen Functionen, though his notion was actually $c(M)+1$. He considered this an "order of connectivity" and referred to surfaces as "onefold, twofold or manifold connected".
It's worth recalling the genus $g(M)$ of a connected surface $M$, which is the maximal number of pairwise disjoint embedded circles that do not disconnect it. The invariant itself was implicit in Riemann's work, though the name is due to Alfred Clebsch in 1865. I do not know who first gave the geometric definition I just outlined. If $M$ is a compact, connected surface (with boundary), we have
$$g(M)=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2}(2-\chi(M)-\#\pi_0(\partial M)),\,&\text{$M$ is orientable},\\
2-\chi(M)-\#\pi_0(\partial M),\,&\text{$M$ is non-orientable}.
\end{cases}
$$
The genus and connectivity are closely related (see below), so perhaps this is the origin of the mistaken formula in Hirsch's Exercise 17(a).
Now, let me address how to compute $c(M)$ for a compact, connected surface (with boundary) $M$ (thanks to @BalarkaSen for figuring this out with me). In the following, "surface" always means "compact surface with boundary". Suppose $V=V_1\cup\dotsc\cup V_r$ is as in the OP. First, recall that it is possible to "cut $M$ along $V$" by removing the interior of the union of sufficiently small tubular neighborhoods of the $V_1,\dotsc,V_r$ (so that the boundaries of the closed tubular neighborhoods still meet pairwise transversely) to obtain a new surface $M^{\prime}$ together with a quotient map $q\colon M^{\prime}\twoheadrightarrow M$ that induces a homeomorphism of $M^{\prime}-q^{-1}(V)$ onto $M-V$ and whose fiber over $p\in V$ has cardinality twice the number of $i$ s.t. $p\in V_i$. Furthermore, $M^{\prime}$ is connected iff $V$ does not disconnect $M$.
Lemma: The elements $[V_1],\dotsc,[V_r]\in H_1(M,\partial M;\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ are linearly independent.
Proof: Fix an $i\in\{1,\dotsc,r\}$. Pick a point $p\in V_i-\bigcup_{j\neq i}V_j$ and the two points $p_1,p_2\in\partial M^{\prime}$ in $q^{-1}(p)$. Then, since $M^{\prime}$ is connected by assumption, we can find a path from $p_1$ to $p_2$ in $M^{\prime}$ that only meets $\partial M^{\prime}$ in its endpoints. The image of this path under $q$ defines a loop in $M$ that intersects $V_i$ in one point (this intersection can easily be arranged to be transverse) and is disjoint from $V_j$ for any $j\neq i$. Thus, it defines a homology class $x_i\in H_1(M)$ whose intersection products $x_i\cdot[V_i]=1$ and $x_i\cdot[V_j]=0$ for $j\neq i$. This implies the claim by elementary linear algebra.
Theorem: $c(M)=\dim_{\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}}H_1(M,\partial M;\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}).$ [This is part (b) of Exercise 9.17.]
Proof: The Lemma implies the RHS is an upper bound. To show this upper bound is achieved, we use the classification of surfaces. First, an orientable closed surface is a sphere with $g(M)$ handles attached. If you take longitude and meridian in every handle, you get the desired $2g(M)$ embedded circles. A non-orientable closed surface is a sphere with $g(M)$ cross-caps attached. If you take the central circle in each cross-cap, you get the desired $g(M)$ embedded circles. Now, you can obtain an arbitrary surface by taking one of these closed surfaces, picking a path in the complement of the hitherto constructed embedded circles and cutting out $b$ small disks along that path to get an additional $b-1$ neat arcs.
Together with some more standard computations, we obtain (hopefully I did not miscalculate)
Corollary If $M$ is a connected surface, then
$$c(M)=\begin{cases}
2g(M)=2-\chi(M),\,&\text{$M$ is closed and orientable},\\
g(M)=2-\chi(M),\,&\text{$M$ is closed and non-orientable},\\
2g(M)+\#\pi_0(\partial M)-1=1-\chi(M),\,&\text{$M$ is not closed and orientable},\\
g(M)+\#\pi_0(\partial M)-1=1-\chi(M),\,&\text{$M$ is not closed and non-orientable}.
\end{cases}$$

As Hirsch says in the introduction to that short chapter, this idea goes back to Riemann himself. :) P.S. Hi :) I used to think that the connectivity was just $\beta_1$, but I will try to read your argument later.

Hi! (from Balarka, too). Thanks for pointing out Hirsch's introduction (I missed it). I was under the mistaken impression Riemann originally defined the genus, but it turns out he used connectivity and I don't actually know whom the geometric definition of genus is due to. In any case, I updated with a small historical paragraph. Let me know if you find any issue with the argument :)
